# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface in html2text

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, typeerror

I'm using python3 to do some web scraping. I want to save a webpage and convert it to text using the following code:

```js
import urllib
import html2text
url='http://www.google.com'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html_content = page.read()
rendered_content = html2text.html2text(html_content)
```

But when I run the code, it reports a type error:

```js
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/html2text-2016.4.2-py3.4.egg/html2text/__init__.py", line 127, in feed
    data = data.replace("</' + 'script>", "</ignore>")
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Could anyone tell me how to deal with this error? Thank you in advance!

Comment: page.read().encode('utf-8')?

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! I tried, but it showed AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'...

Comment: sorry,  should be decode.

Answer (score 1):

I took the time to investigate this, and it turns out to be easily resolved.

### Why You Got This Error

The problem is one of bad input: when you called `page.read()`, a *byte string* was returned, rather than a regular string.

[Byte strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824539/what-is-a-python-bytestring) are Python's way of dealing with unfamiliar character encodings: basically there are characters in the raw text that don't map to Unicode (Python 3's default character encoding).

Because Python doesn't know what encoding to use, Python instead represents such strings using raw bytes - this is how all data is represented internally anyway - and lets the programmer decide what encoding to use.

Regular string methods called on these byte strings - such as `replace()`, which `html2text` tried to use - fail because byte strings don't have these methods defined.

### Solution

```
html_content = page.read().decode('iso-8859-1')
```

Padraic Cunningham's solution in the comments is correct in its essence: you have to first tell Python which character encoding to use to try to map these bytes to correct character set.

Unfortunately, this *particular* text doesn't use Unicode, so asking it to decode using the `UTF-8` encoding throws an error.

The *correct* encoding to use is actually contained in the request headers itself under the `Content-Type` header - this is a standard header that all HTTP-compliant server responses are guaranteed to provide.

Simply calling `page.info().get_content_charset()` returns the value of this header, which in this case is `iso-8859-1`. From there, you can decode it correctly using `iso-8859-1`, so that regular tools can operate on it normally.

### A More Generic Solution

```
charset_encoding = page.info().get_content_charset()
html_content = page.read().decode(charset_encoding)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! html2text works now! But now I have another problem. When I try to print rendered_content, it reports the unicode encode error again. It says UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xbb' in position 345: ordinal not in range(128). Could you tell me how to solve this one?

Comment: I have no idea what 'rendered_content' is. The error is obvious though: instead of 'iso-8859-1', something is trying to encode your string with raw ASCII. ASCII doesn't work with these characters. You're better served by asking this issue as a separate question, so that more people than I can address it.

Answer (score 0):

The stream returned by urlopen is indicated as being a bytestream by b as the first character before the quoted string.  If you exclude it, as in the appended code it seems to work as input for html2txt.

```
import urllib
import html2text
url='http://www.google.com'
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as page:
    html_content = page.read()
charset_encoding = page.info().get_content_charset()
rendered_content = html2text.html2text(str(html_content)[1:], charset_encoding)
```

Revised using suggestions about encoding. Yes, it's a hack, but it runs. Not using str() means the original TypeError problem remains.

Comment: This isn't the right way to solve this. Using `str()` with the `b` removed just wraps the byte string in a string wrapper - it's a hack. It doesn't solve the underlying problem, which is that there are characters in the string Python doesn't know how to represent. People trying to use this code will eventually run into frustrating encoding/decoding issues later on.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! It works now!