# AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get some information from google finance but I am getting this error

> AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'split'

Here is my python code:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

symbolsfile = open("Stocklist.txt")

symbolslist = symbolsfile.read()

thesymbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

i=0


while i<len (thesymbolslist):
    theurl = "http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=" + thesymbolslist[i] + "&i=10&p=25m&f=c"
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen (theurl)
    print(thesymbolslist[i] + " price is " + thepage.split()[len(thepage.split())-1])
    i= i+1
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `thepage.split()[len(thepage.split())-1])`

Comment: i am trying to get the page into a list and then get the last attribute from that list and print it.

Comment: You need to `read()` from the `thepage` to get an actual string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### The Cause of the Problem

This is because `urllib.request.urlopen (theurl)` returns an object representing the connection, not a string.

---

### The Solution

To read data from this connection and actually get a string, you need to do

```
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl).read()
```

and then the rest of your code should follow naturally.

### Addendum to the Solution

Occasionally, the string itself contains an unrecognised character encoding glyph, in which case Python converts it into a [bytestring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824539/what-is-a-python-bytestring).

The right approach to dealing with that is to find the correct character encoding and decode the bytestring into a regular string using it, as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877016/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface-in-html2text/36879764#36879764):

```
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
# read the correct character encoding from `Content-Type` request header
charset_encoding = thepage.info().get_content_charset()
# apply encoding
thepage = thepage.read().decode(charset_encoding)
```

It is sometimes safe to make the assumption that the character encoding is  `utf-8`, in which case

```
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl).read().decode('utf-8')
```

does work more often than not. It's a statistically good guess if nothing else.

Comment: once i did that it gave me this error:
         TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: It's because the encoding of the string you're receiving is not something Python understands. Give me a minute to provide a fix.

Comment: Your solution is more robust since it does not depend on the source encoding, so OP: better mark this one the right answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Checking the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) might save you time in the future. It says that the urlopen() method returns an [HTTPResponse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse) object which has a read() method. In Python 3, you need to decode the output from the source encoding, in this case UTF-8. So just write

```
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl).read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: once i did that it gave me this error: TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: Python 3? Then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699362/python3-error-typeerror-cant-convert-bytes-object-to-str-implicitly/16699591#16699591 Try `thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl).read().decode('utf-8')`

Comment: @le_m That assumes the default encoding is `utf-8` - which is often true, but is not necessarily the encoding sent over. The correct way to do it is to check the encoding in the headers and apply that.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan You are right, of course, but since OP is just querying google.com we can safely assume UTF-8.

Comment: @le_m [You would be surprised what character encodings Google uses in lieu of UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877016/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface-in-html2text/36879764#36879764)...