# using urllib in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

I have been coding a webcrawler in python 3, and everything seems to be working. 
So I decided to use urllib to get the source code of the pages I am going to crawl.
 But I get a name error that says:

```
    name 'urlib' is not defined
```

here is my python code:

```
def get_url(url):
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return source

def getNextTarget(page):
    startLink = page.find("<a href=")
    if startLink == -1:
        return None, 0
    startQuote = page.find('"', startLink)
    endQuote = page.find('"', startQuote + 1)
    url = page[startQuote + 1 : endQuote]
    return url, endQuote

def findAllLinks(page):
while True:
    url, endpos = getNextTarget(page)
    if url:
        print(url)
        page = page[endpos:]
    else:
        break

findAllLinks(get_url("https://xkcd.com/"))
```

Sorry if this question has already been asked. 
Thank you for your help in advance.

P.S: the main prblem is with the get_url() function.

Comment: `urllib` has two `l`s. But since you used a `from ... import`, you just need to do `source = urlopen(url)`.

Comment: same error when I fix the single l. and changing the sorce to just 'urlopen(url)' gives an error saying: AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: Can you update your question with the "fixed" code then?

Comment: sure thing, it is updated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `get_url` function returns a connection object and not a string. So you cannot do a `page.find()` on it in `getNextTarget`. You should do a `.read()` on your connection object to get a string.

Refer:

[AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'split'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369901/attributeerror-httpresponse-object-has-no-attribute-split)
https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html

Comment: sorry, bit of a noob. can you please clarify.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you so much for your help! :)