# Added characters to string when exiting subprocces

Tags: python

I am calling a subprocess and returning a string if there is an error.
Code example:

When calling the process:

```
def read_plan_with_break():
    comand = " python script.py "
    proc = subprocess.Popen(comand.split(), shell=False, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE)
    if proc.wait() != 0:
        output, err = proc.communicate() 
        print (err)
        return "Error in subprocess"
    return True
```

when exiting the subprocess:

```
def fatal_error():
  print("Some message", file=sys.stderr)
  exit(1)
```

My problem is that the `stderr` output is : `b'Some message\r\n'`
I can erase the `\r\n` with `strip` but have no idea why there is a `b` at the beginning and the `'` at the start and the end.

Does anyone know why this occurs?

EDIT:
I have tried `err.split()[2:-1]` to get rid of the `b'` but it cuts off the start of the `Some message`

If I get a down-vote, please explain so I can improve and make better questions in the future

Comment: It just means its a bytestring. You cant remove the `b` by substringing, its not part of the string. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824539/what-is-a-python-bytestring)

Comment: err.decode() will help you

Comment: @TheClonerx Thank you, answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @PaulRooney It si my first time hearing about bytestrings, i am new to python, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

err is a bytestring, you should decode it first by err.decode(), this returns the string