# Correct way to write JSON data returned from a SPARQL query in Python

Tags: python, json, sparql, sparqlwrapper

I'm using python3 to make SPARQL queries.  I need to read a Virtuoso database and output triples.  Some of the data in the triples contains special characters like linefeeds and such.

Anyway, I can get the data out like this:

```
queryString = "some query"
sparql.setQuery(queryString)
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
try:
    jsonData = sparql.query()
    for result in jsonData:
        print('Result: ***')
        f.write(str(result) + '\n')
except:
    print("Oops:", sys.exc_info()[0], file=sys.stderr)
```

When I do this, I get the following output in the file:

```
b'{\n'
b'  "head" : {\n'
b'    "vars" : [\n'
b'      "subject",\n'
b'      "predicate",\n'
b'      "object"\n'
b'    ]\n'
b'  },\n'
b'  "results" : {\n'
b'    "bindings" : [\n'
b'      {\n'
b'        "predicate" : {\n'
b'          "type" : "uri",\n'
b'          "value" : "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type"\n'
b'        },\n'
b'        "subject" : {\n'
b'          "type" : "uri",\n'
b'          "value" : "http://www.ontologyrepository.com/CommonCoreOntologies/delimits"\n'
b'        },\n'
b'        "object" : {\n'
b'          "type" : "uri",\n'
b'          "value" : "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#InverseFunctionalProperty"\n'
b'        }\n'
b'      },\n'
```

and so on.  I'm not sure what the `b` prefix does on these lines.  Anyway, I'm having trouble reading this in with the JSON libraries.  So I would *prefer* to write it with JSON.

I would like to replace the for loop with a simple thing like

```
json.dump(jsonData, f)
```

or

```
json.dumps(jsonData, f)
```

When I do that I get the error message `Oops: <class 'TypeError'>`.
I notice that the type of `jsonData` is `<class 'SPARQLWrapper.Wrapper.QueryResult'>`.

Is the SPARQL query not returning JSON?  Is there some other transformation I have to make?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using some Python library, not strict Python. Specific version details (Python, that library, target Virtuoso) may matter. For some reason, each line of the output file is being wrapped in `b' '` (i.e., it's not just a `b` prefix) and the linefeeds within the JSON are being replaced with `\n` -- which I cannot immediately explain, but it seems that cleanup should be fairly easy with any number of tools, if we cannot figure out how to prevent these.

Comment: You might try using Virtuoso's `define output:format "fmt"` [output pragma](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtSpongerLinkedDataHooksIntoSPARQL#OUTPUT%20Pragmas) to start the query string, [specifying "JSON"](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlimplementatioptragmas/#rdfsparqlimplementatioptragmassfs), instead of Python's `sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)`

Comment: My computer system is going down until possibly Wednesday, but I'll try the output:format first thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The b in front of your String means that your String is not an string but an byte string and your bytes are interpreted as chars for printing.  [Look here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824539/what-is-a-python-bytestring)

For the next time it would be easier if you tell us more of your problem. What library you are using, which version, example query etc.

In your case i assume your are using SPARQLWrapper Library. You are very close to solve your problem, you only need to convert your QueryResult. Just call `jsonData = sparql.query().convert()` instead of `jsonData = sparql.query()` and you will get an dict which can be written to a json file with `json.dump`.