# How can I convert this language to actual numbers and text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I am working on natural language processing project with deep learning and I downloaded a word embedding file. The file is in `.bin` format. I can open that file with

```
file = open("cbow.bin", "rb")
```

But when I type

```
file.read(100)
```

I get

```
b'4347907 300\n</s> H\xe1\xae:0\x16\xc1:\xbfX\xa7\xbaR8\x8f\xba\xa0\xd3\xee9K\xfe\x83::m\xa49\xbc\xbb\x938\xa4p\x9d\xbat\xdaA:UU\xbe\xba\x93_\xda9\x82N\x83\xb9\xaeG\xa7\xb9\xde\xdd\x90\xbaww$\xba\xfdba:\x14.\x84:R\xb8\x81:0\x96\x0b:\x96\xfc\x06'
```

What is this language and How can I convert it into actual numbers and text using python?

Comment: This might be the machine executable. Where did you get it from?

Comment: It's from the "mazajak" project.

Comment: "The file is in `.bin` format"—`.bin` isn't a format. It's a file extension. Lots of applications use `.bin` file extensions for arbitrary binary data, there's no standard.

Comment: It's unusual to have a non-executable binary file that's not accompanied by some sort of documentation on how to interpret it. Have you tried contacting the authors of the file?

Comment: @jolitti no I didn't. I will try to do that.

Comment: Best of luck. If you manage to get to the bottom of it, be sure to answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This weird language you are referring to is a python [bytestring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824539/what-is-a-python-bytestring).

As [@jolitti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8831742/jolitti) implied that you won't be able to convert this particular bytestring to readable text.

If the bytestring contained any characters you recognize then would have been displayed like this.

```py
b'Guido van Rossum'
```

Comment: So, Do I need to contact  the authors of the file? How would they help me?

Comment: Yes, please ask them. The file you have is just a stream of bytes and not something to be parsed. I don't understand what word embedding file is. But reading a short summary on word embedding, I would guess this is a trained model and you would have to _load_ this file to use it.